# CSV - how to fix encoding issues

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file, which says it has UTF-8 encoding (as per Notepad++), but it's obviously not correct and when I try to decode it using other typical encoding, it does not work and it is still not readable.

I just wanted to ask for an advice, if there is a way, how to fix the encoding issues?
I've also tried to detect the econding via Python, but it says UTF-8 as well

```
with open("data.csv", 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))

# check what the character encoding might be
print(result)
```

[image]

Example:

[image]

```
Location
Switzerland Â» Lake Geneva Â» VÃ©senaz
Germany Â» BÃ¶nningstedt
Switzerland Â» Lake of Zurich Â» StÃ¤fa ZH
Denmark Â» Svendborg
Germany Â» Bayern Â» MÃ¼nchen
Switzerland Â» Lake Constance Â» Uttwil
Switzerland Â» Neuenburgersee Â» Yvonand 
Denmark Â» Svendborg
Germany Â» Bayern Â» Boote+service Oberbayern
Italy Â» Dormelletto 
Switzerland Â» Seengen
Switzerland Â» Lake of Zurich Â» StÃ¤fa am ZÃ¼richsee
Italy Â» Lake Garda Â» Moniga del Garda (BS)
Switzerland Â» Zugersee Â» Neuheim
Switzerland Â» VierwaldstÃ¤ttersee Â» 6004
Switzerland Â» Safenwil
Switzerland Â» Lake Constance Â» Uttwil
Denmark Â» Svendborg
"France Â» MARTGUES, MARTIGUES"
Germany Â» Bayern Â» Forchheim/Ofr.
Germany Â» Bayern Â» MÃ¼nchen
Switzerland Â» Luganersee Â» Caslano
Germany Â» Nordrhein-Westfalen Â» WSC Hopp / MÃ¶nchengladbach
"Germany Â» BOOTSSERVICE ENK IN TREIS KARDEN, BOOTSSERVICE ENK"
```

Comment: Hard to help you without original data file with the right encoding.

Comment: Note: never open a CSV file in Excel by simply double clicking on it. Start with a blank Excel and use Data > From Text/CSV to import it with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The file is correctly encode as UTF-8. But you later display it as UTF-8 on a system that would expect Latin1 or cp1252 encoding.

Here is an evidence:

```
t = '''Location
Switzerland Â» Lake Geneva Â» VÃ©senaz
Germany Â» BÃ¶nningstedt
Switzerland Â» Lake of Zurich Â» StÃ¤fa ZH
Denmark Â» Svendborg
Germany Â» Bayern Â» MÃ¼nchen
Switzerland Â» Lake Constance Â» Uttwil
Switzerland Â» Neuenburgersee Â» Yvonand 
Denmark Â» Svendborg
Germany Â» Bayern Â» Boote+service Oberbayern
Italy Â» Dormelletto 
Switzerland Â» Seengen
Switzerland Â» Lake of Zurich Â» StÃ¤fa am ZÃ¼richsee
Italy Â» Lake Garda Â» Moniga del Garda (BS)
Switzerland Â» Zugersee Â» Neuheim
Switzerland Â» VierwaldstÃ¤ttersee Â» 6004
Switzerland Â» Safenwil
Switzerland Â» Lake Constance Â» Uttwil
Denmark Â» Svendborg
"France Â» MARTGUES, MARTIGUES"
Germany Â» Bayern Â» Forchheim/Ofr.
Germany Â» Bayern Â» MÃ¼nchen
Switzerland Â» Luganersee Â» Caslano
Germany Â» Nordrhein-Westfalen Â» WSC Hopp / MÃ¶nchengladbach
"Germany Â» BOOTSSERVICE ENK IN TREIS KARDEN, BOOTSSERVICE ENK"
'''
print(t.encode('latin1').decode())
```

On my unicode enabled systems it gives as expected:

```
Location
Switzerland » Lake Geneva » Vésenaz
Germany » Bönningstedt
Switzerland » Lake of Zurich » Stäfa ZH
Denmark » Svendborg
Germany » Bayern » München
Switzerland » Lake Constance » Uttwil
Switzerland » Neuenburgersee » Yvonand 
Denmark » Svendborg
Germany » Bayern » Boote+service Oberbayern
Italy » Dormelletto 
Switzerland » Seengen
Switzerland » Lake of Zurich » Stäfa am Zürichsee
Italy » Lake Garda » Moniga del Garda (BS)
Switzerland » Zugersee » Neuheim
Switzerland » Vierwaldstättersee » 6004
Switzerland » Safenwil
Switzerland » Lake Constance » Uttwil
Denmark » Svendborg
"France » MARTGUES, MARTIGUES"
Germany » Bayern » Forchheim/Ofr.
Germany » Bayern » München
Switzerland » Luganersee » Caslano
Germany » Nordrhein-Westfalen » WSC Hopp / Mönchengladbach
"Germany » BOOTSSERVICE ENK IN TREIS KARDEN, BOOTSSERVICE ENK"
```

Said differently, the file is correct, it is correctly read by `read_csv`. Only the next part is plain wrong. You are not using Excel, are you?